# SELECT how many movies where made in a year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two rows in my database, one row is for the movies, the other one is for the year a movie was made

I would like to select every movies and check how many were made in a specific year, it has to be every year.

The output should look like this:

```
2018 = 819
2017 = 910
2016 = 128
2015 = 539
```

What I tried:

```
SELECT LEFT(movie,4), COUNT(year) FROM movies GROUP BY LEFT(movie,4);
```

but it only outputs the name of the movies

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Perhaps you have *columns* in a *table*

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Select year, count(1) from movies group by year
```

Answer (score 1):

try this simple query Use **GROUP BY**

```
Select count(*),year from movies group by year
```

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
Select year, count(movie) from movies group by year
```